# What ROS Java Architecture can support?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am new to ROS Java environment, base on what I have seen so far I want to confirm with the community what ROS Java architecture can support.

1. Is ROS Java environment use a hosted container architecture?  What I mean is that, after I create my ROS Java code / bean I have to deploy into the ROS container in order for it to run?
2. If this is the case, is it possible not to use a hosted container architecture to run my ROS Java code?  Can I run my ROS code standalone outside to ROS container to interact with the ROS Core?  I need to deploy my Java code into another Java container environment, which does not allow me to deploy to ROS container environment.

Thanks,
Mason Tran

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198975/what-ros-java-architecture-can-support?/) by [Mason Tran](https://answers.ros.org/users/21037/mason-tran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosjava implementation does not require hosted container architecture. Generally it's built into freestanding executables.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0